# vCenter server (web client and vsphere client) can't read data from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, vmware

I was trying to upgrade the vcenter version from 5.5 U3E to 6.5 U3. Upgrade process failed and we restored the changes from snapshots and SQL Server database restored from backup. Post restoration, Inventory is empty and unable to connect through domain ID.
In SQL Database, found two schema using. One is dbo and otherone is VMW. While trying SQL query, vCenter Data's are available in VMW Schema, but vcenter can't read the data from VMW. Configuration are as below:

1. VCenter Server - VC Version 5.5 U3E, Installed on Windows 2008 R2 server
2. SQL Server version is MS SQL 2008 R2 Ent Service Pack 2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQLwP.png)

Comment: But of those Microsoft Products are completely unsupported. I would suggest upgrading your back end to a supported version and then worry about getting the front end upgraded.

Comment: Windows server for vCenter server is already upgraded to Windows 2012 R2, but issue still persist.

Comment: *"MS SQL 2008 R2 Ent Service Pack 2."* SQL Server 2008 R2's support ended last year, and SP3 for SQL Server 2008 R2 came out in October 2011. This means your server hasn't had any updates in almost 9 years. That is a significant concern. 2008 SP2 has multiple known security issues (Meltdown and Spectre to name a couple).

Comment: Is there any way to move/alter/copy data from VMW schema database to default schema i.e. dbo ?

Comment: You can move an object from one schema to another, yes. [ALTER SCHEMA (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Issue resolved now...

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2075440
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1005157

If the schema is not DBO ensure that sysadmin is not selected for the user under Server Roles. 
I have removed the User ID from Sysadmin group, and VC start reading data from SQ Database.